# Magento Products Ordered Report - Bundle Products

Tags: php, magento

I'm looking at customising a Magento report. I understand the default Products Order report obtains product sales data from the aggregate data tables. However, these only contain information on simple product types within the bundle, rather than the bundle product ids themselves.

How does one go about producing a report simply for bundle product sales?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at http://magentocoder.jigneshpatel.co.in/create-custom-reports-in-magento-admin/

You should be able to accomplish what you want by changing this line of code

```
$compositeTypeIds = Array (
                    '0' => 'grouped',
                    '1' => 'simple',
                    '2' => 'bundle'
                    );

$productTypes = $this->getConnection()->quoteInto(' AND (e.type_id NOT IN (?))', $compositeTypeIds);
```

to

```
$compositeTypeIds = Array (
                    '2' => 'bundle'
                    );

$productTypes = $this->getConnection()->quoteInto(' AND (e.type_id IN (?))', $compositeTypeIds);
```